# I need help for Matlab vectorization of this code

Tags: matlab, vectorization

I am new on MatLAB, i don't know proper basics of vectorization.. 
I am trying to vectorize this function.

```
function  indc  =  PatchSearch(X, row, col, off, nv, S, I)

[N M]   =   size(I);
f2      =   size(X,2);

rmin    =   max( row-S, 1 );
rmax    =   min( row+S, N );
cmin    =   max( col-S, 1 );
cmax    =   min( col+S, M );

idx     =   I(rmin:rmax, cmin:cmax);
idx     =   idx(:);
B       =   X(idx, :);        
v       =   X(off, :);


dis     =   (B(:,1) - v(1)).^2;
for k = 2:f2
    dis   =  dis + (B(:,k) - v(k)).^2;
end
dis   =  dis./f2;
[val,ind]   =  sort(dis); 
indc        =  idx( ind(1:nv) );
%indc = idx(dis<250);
```

I need help from some experts for vectorizating this function
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the following loopy portion of your code -

```
dis     =   (B(:,1) - v(1)).^2;
for k = 2:f2
    dis   =  dis + (B(:,k) - v(k)).^2;
end
```

With this [`bsxfun`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) implementation -

```
dis = sum(bsxfun(@minus,B,v).^2,2);
```

The assumption here is that `f2` is the number of columns in `B`, which is the same as the number of elements in `v` and looking at your code the way `B` and `v` are initialized, that seems to be quite right.

Comment: @AbeeraGohar Looking at your other latest posted question on Stackoverflow, it doesn't look like that loop or even this function might be the bottleneck. Regarding reducing the function calls, if you only share one function with us, we can can't reduce the number of function calls to it, unless you also share with us the calling function.

Comment: i need to implement this piece of code on gpu.. i tried directly and implemented on gpu but it took long time bcoz of too many for loops. then i found that implementation on gpu after vectorization will reduce time to run this code.. now em stuck with vectorization.. i thought i will start from scratch/most independent function and move to most complex function.. 
Please guide me how to move on

Comment: I am posting the function which calls it and all functions called in it .. even if you give me proper direction it will be appreciated

Comment: can i have ur email address?

Comment: @AbeeraGohar Let's just keep it on Stackoverflow. Thank you for understanding.

Comment: ok @Divakar how to vectorize this?
[M,N,K]=size(x);
y = zeros(K,M*N);
X = zeros(K,M*N);
temp = zeros(M,N);

for k=1:K
     temp = W_matrix*x(:,:,k)*W_matrix';
     y(k,:)=temp(:)';
end

X = Dct_matrix*y;

Comment: @Sam Don't post queries not related to the answer here in comments. Ask a new question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution using `repmat` and `sum`:

Replace the loop and the line above it with this code.

```
dis=sum((B-repmat(v,size(B,1),1)).^2,2);
```

Comment: there is issue with matrix dimensions .

Comment: If you mean that you expected the output `dis` as a column vector instead of a row vector it is solved.